# Prevent link to own class in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

All class name instanced«s in a class' documentation are linking to itself. Is there an option to prevent this?

This is particularly relevant when I have several classes with similar names and need to navigate through their documentation.

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.13 to document c++ project.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it yet, but according to the [documentation of Doxygen](http://doxygen.nl/autolink.html):

> All words in the documentation that correspond to a documented class
>   and contain at least one non-lower case character will automatically
>   be replaced by a link to the page containing the documentation of the
>   class. **If you want to prevent that a word that corresponds to a
>   documented class is replaced by a link you should put a % in front of
>   the word.** To link to an all lower case symbol, use \ref.

Comment: Bit of an old reference, though text is still OK. Better link: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/autolink.html#linkclass